# Econometrics/Statistics, variance and means

Tags: statistics, economics, means

here's the problem I can't figure out on my own:
The weight of a randomly selected student, (W), has a mean of $170$ and variance of $10$. Defining the new random variable ($Y$): the total weight of two students carrying a $5$ lb backpack each. What is the mean and variance of ($Y$)?

I don't know if defining the constant, $5$, is worthwhile, or even the steps to take to solve this. Any help's greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: I think first you must help us. what is the relation between $X$ and $Y$? what is 170? what is 10? kg? lb? cm?...

Comment: I guess W is supposed to be normally distributed? If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are the weights of each student then we can assume that they are two independent, normally distributed random variables. What have you been told about adding such variables? Distribution, mean and variance?

Comment: Alright, to answer the question: the mean is 170 lbs., so S^2 is 10, standard deviation (s) is 3.162, and the variable is assumed normal distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $W_1,W_2$ denote the random variables for weights for the randomly selected students.   Let $Y=W_1 + W_2 + 10.$    Assuming $W_1$ are $W_2$ are independent, we get:

$E[Y]=E[W_1+W_2+10] = E[W_1]+E[W_2]+E[10] = 170 + 170 + 10 = \boxed{350}$

and

$Var[Y]=Var(W_1 + W_2+10) = Var(W_1) + Var(W_2) + Var(10)= 10+10+0=\boxed{20}$